# ListTile title makes it's children take full width no matter what

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to insert a `TextField` in `ListTile`'s `title` and make it take only the width of the text inside. It works perfectly outside of a `ListTile`, but inside a `title` it takes full width of a `ListTile` no matter what. What can I do?

[image: screenshot]

**DartPad:** https://dartpad.dev/87f397c71f3e449e866cea9914d13bb0

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IntrinsicWidth(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Title',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              child: Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                child: InkWell(
                  onLongPress: () {
                    print('Longpress fired');
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          hintText: 'Title',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text('subtitle'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I managed to make the `TextField` take needed space with this code, but now I am sufferng from overflow:

[image]

```
ListTile(
  title: Expanded(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        IntrinsicWidth(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: tried a `Row` with two children: your `TextField` and `Expanded`?

Comment: @pskink yes, this way `TextField` does not show at all. I just updated my question, because I kinda found a solution, but encountered another problem.

Comment: the idea with `Row` and `Expanded` works just fine: `body: ListView(
children: [
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
ListTile(
leading: Icon(Icons.alarm),
title: Row(
children: [
IntrinsicWidth(
child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(),),
),
Expanded(
child: Container(),
),
],
),
trailing: Icon(Icons.android),
),
],
),
`

Comment: @pskink you are right, your code works. However the overflow issue still exists. I tried using `SingleChildScrollView` between `ListTile` and `IntrinsicWidth` and it works fine. Little downside is that `SingleChildScrollView` adds a little bit of padding to the bottom of itself.

Comment: what overflow do you mean?

Comment: @pskink when text width is more than it's parent. I added the screenshot in the update of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a SizedBox for the trailing property in ListView.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to just create your own custom widget for this, it's actually not that hard. Looks something like:

```
Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: use an approriate MediaQuery here,
                  child: TextField(),
                ),
                Text('subtitle')
              ],
            ),
```

Maybe even throw in a padding in the `Container`.